# sql list records with no parents

Tags: sql

What's the best way to get the list of parent ID that have no child?

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    ID PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT
);

CREATE TABLE child (
    ID PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT
    ParentID    INT NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way:

```
SELECT P.ParentID
FROM dbo.Parent P
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ParentId FROM child) C
ON P.ParentId = C.ParentId
WHERE C.ParentID IS NULL
```

This is another way:

```
SELECT P.ParentID
FROM dbo.Parent P
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Child WHERE ParentId = P.ParentID)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select id from parent
where id not in (select distinct parentid from child)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your flavour of sql:

```
select ID from parent minus select ParentID from child
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Parent ID 
from Parent 
where ParentID NOT IN Select distinct ParentID from ChildTable
```

this would work :)